# How to parse 0000-00-00 00:00:00?

Tags: mysql, parsing, time, go

I'm parsing some time values from a mysql database and some of them are zero. Why does Go fail to parse this and how can I fix it?

```
checkTime := "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05", checkTime)
if err !=nil{
    log.Errorf("err %v, checkTime %v, ID %v", err, checkTime, bk.ID)
}
```

I get:

```
err parsing time "0000-00-00 00:00:00": month out of range, checkin 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Comment: As an aside: Newer versions of MySQL will reject the date `0000-00-00` when SQL strict mode is enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That does not parse because there was no year zero.  After 1 B.C. is 1 A.D.

With most contexts, it probably makes sense to make a special check for year zero and store a NULL value in its place.

---

From a practical viewpoint, any dates given as being in a year between 1 AD and around 600 A.D. are poorly documented and likely wrong.  Somewhere in there are a few missed years.  Academics aren't sure how many, but they mostly agree that at least 4 years are missing and maybe as many as 8 or 10.  That is, the year 2015 actually should be 2019 to 2029.

Comment: Actually this is not the case. Year `0` is parsable by Go's `time` package (as shown in my answer). The problem is the month `0`.

Answer (score 7):

First a comile time error in your code: there is no `log.Errorf()` function (that is if you're using the standard [`log`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/) package). Instead use for example [`log.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Printf).

Second, as your error states: `month out of range`. Month is in range if `1..12`. A month value of `0` or `00` is invalid. See [valid months here](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Month).

The zero time (or the more precise term: the [zero value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of the type [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time)) is as printed by:

```
log.Println("Zero time is:", time.Time{}.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
```

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Zero time is: 0001-01-01 00:00:00
```

Note that year, month and day are all `1`.

Also note that even though days start from `1`, day `0` is also accepted and is interpreted as `-1` day from the first day of month specified by the year and month parts.

So while `"0000-01-01 00:00:00"` can be parsed and properly gives `"0000-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC"`, the time `"0000-01-00 00:00:00"` will give `"-0001-12-31 00:00:00 +0000 UTC"`.

The exact date `"0000-00-00 00:00:00"` represents the zero date from your source (MySql db?), and so in Go when this date is detected I would return the zero value for the Go `time.Time` so you can check it from Go with the [`Time.IsZero()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.IsZero) method. Use this simple helper function to parse your times:

```
func parseTime(s string) (time.Time, err) {
    if s == "0000-00-00 00:00:00" {
        return time.Time{}, nil
    }
    return time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05", s)
}
```

See the examples in action on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/--HgEx-Cnr).

Answer (score 2):

The zero value of type Time is [January 1, year 1, 00:00:00.000000000 UTC](https://golang.org/src/time/time.go). So there is no month 0 in Go.

Comment: Zero value of `time.Time` being year 1 does not imply that year cannot be 0. There is time before year 1. Year `0` is parsable by the `time` package. It's month `0` that cannot be parsed (because it's invalid).